# Logistic regression: ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I want to use logistic regression to predict and plot a [curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H2IY.png) from an Excel  dataset and get its slope coefficients. However, when I run the code (see below) the error " ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'. " occurs.

I read in similar questions that the y values should be 'int' type but I don't want to convert it because the y numbers are between 1.66 and 0.44...

Is there a solution for this kind of cases or should I try another regression model?

Thanks a lot in advance

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


df = pd.read_excel('Fatigue2.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet4')

X = df[['Strain1', 'Temperature1']]
y = df['Cycles1']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=101)

#poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
#X_ = poly.fit_transform(X_train)

LR = LogisticRegression()
LR.fit(X_train,y_train)

g = sns.lmplot(x='Cycles1', y='Strain1', hue = 'Temperature1', data=df, fit_reg= False)
g.set(xscale='log', yscale ='log')
g.set_axis_labels("Cycles (log N)", "Strain")

print ('Coefficients : ', LR.coef_, 'Intercept :', LR.intercept_)
```

About the data, I have 97 values in total in an Excel sheet:

```
Cycles1   Strain1    Temperature1

27631     1.66         650
...       ...          650
6496220   0.44         650
```

Comment: Logistic Regression is used to predict discrete labels or categories. What you are describing (retrieving slopes, numeric values from ... to ...) sounds more like a Linear Regression case.

Comment: Thank you for this explaination. Indeed, it's working with linear regression, but it returns me only one coefficient, and I need a higher precision. I'm going to try with polynomial regression then.

Comment: your `PolynomialFeatures` preprocessor should be able to construct the polynomials for the Linear Regression for you. There even might be some preprocessor for combining features. btw. the number of coefficients should equal the number of features you put into your model.

Comment: 'btw. the number of coefficients should equal the number of features you put into your mode', this I don't get: from what I did understand, the degree I put in the PolynomialFeature is influencing the number of coefficients, like degree = 2 --> ['1', 'x', 'y', 'x^2', 'x y', 'y^2']. right? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: sry i was referring to the linear case without polynomial features. For the polynomial case it should be the number of features times the degree (+1 if you're estimating with constant included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LogisticRegression` from `sklearn` is a classifier, i.e. it expects that the response variable is categorical.

Your task is of regression. Moreover, the plot does not seem to have the asymptotic behavior of a logit on the right. You may have better results using a polynomial regression as described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#polynomial-regression-extending-linear-models-with-basis-functions).

Comment: Yeah, I changed it in polynomial rgression and it's much better ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Based on [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target.html#sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target) `type_of_target(y)`:

> Determine the type of data indicated by the target.
>
> Note that this type is the most specific type that can be inferred.
> For example:
>
> - `binary` is more specific but compatible with `multiclass`.
> - `multiclass` of integers is more specific but compatible with
>   `continuous`.
> - `multilabel-indicator` is more specific but compatible with
>   `multiclass-multioutput`.

> ### Parameters
>
> `y` : array-like

> ### Returns
>
> target_type : string

> One of:
>
> - 'continuous': `y` is an array-like of floats that are not all
>   integers, and is 1d or a column vector.
> - ...

#### change `y` as `y.astype(int)`